# encode bitmap to webp with libwebp on Android pre api 14 device

Tags: android, bitmap, webp

I want to encode `Bitmap` to webp on Android 2.x device with `libwebp`. Below is my testing code

```
public static int createWebPImage(Bitmap bitmap, String outFilePath) {
    Log.d(TAG, "create webp image");
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BitmapCompat.getAllocationByteCount(bitmap));
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    return nativeCreateWebPImage(buffer, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), outFilePath);
}
```

And the jni implementation is

```
nativeCreateWebPImage(JNIEnv *env, jclass type, jobject directBuffer, jint width, jint height, jstring outFilePath_) {
    const char *outFilePath = env->GetStringUTFChars(outFilePath_, 0);
    int ret = 0;
    FILE* file = NULL;
    if ((file = fopen(outFilePath, "w+")) != NULL) {
        uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t *) env->GetDirectBufferAddress(directBuffer);
        LOGD("size of the bitmap %lu", (unsigned long) env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(directBuffer));
        uint8_t* output = (uint8_t *) malloc((size_t) env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(directBuffer));
        size_t n = WebPEncodeRGBA(buffer, width, height, width, 0.9, &output);
        if (n <= 0) {
            LOGD("webp encode failed");
            ret = -1;
        } else {
            LOGD("write to file");
            if (fwrite(output, sizeof(uint8_t), n, file) != n) {
                LOGD("write file error");
                ret = -1;
            }
        }

        free(output);
        fclose(file);
    } else {
        LOGD("open file error %s", outFilePath);
        ret = -1;
    }
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(outFilePath_, outFilePath);
    return ret;
}
```

The resulting file was created successfully, but the encoded image was  totally broken. The image seems filled with the wrong data. Is the parameters wrong when calling `WebPEncodeRGBA`? The bitmap configuration is `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`.

How can I correctly encode `Bitmap` to webp with the API call `WebPEncodeRGBA`?

Comment: pre API 14 currently (as 6th-Jan-2016) 3.2% of devices that access Google Play ( http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html ) . Are you sure you want to have all this trouble to such a small population?

Comment: @Budius Currently I compress bitmap to jpeg on Android 2.x device, so if this trouble can't be solved, I will keep using jpeg on Android 2.x device. The reason I prefer webp is the size is smaller than jpeg.

Comment: Hey @alijandro . How can connect with you. Do you have public repo for this implementaion. I need to encode decode animated webp in android api > 19.

Comment: Hi @CrackerKSR see [this](https://github.com/WanghongLin/AndroidWebP) example, only have decode example for animated webp.

Answer (score 1):

After read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/api) from Google, I found the stride parameter was wrong. It should be counted as bytes. Then I changed the encode function call to

```
WebPEncodeRGBA(buffer, width, height, width * 4 /* stride in bytes */, 0.9, &output);
```

It worked.