# Problem while saving image as bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap, webp

I am trying to save an array of bitmaps as webp image in android, but while processing more than one, the application getting terminated.

```
    for(int i=0;i<bitmapArr.length;i++){
                        try{
                            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmapArr[i].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP,100,fileOutputStream);
                            fileOutputStream.close();
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Exception:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6e800000 in tid 19366
```

Comment: It might be cause _Out of Memory_ exception.

Comment: @Piyush I added the exception

Comment: This is not the proper exception. Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632379/encode-bitmap-to-webp-with-libwebp-on-android-pre-api-14-device)? If you want to bitmap to _WebP_

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Android hardware acceleration in your manifest.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Read this post for same issues.[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked)